# Iteration of similarly named variables in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I have say 4 variables say.

```
var1="a";
var2="b";
var3="c";
var4="d";
```

I would like to iterate them in a for loop in a way that I use only var and use 1,2,3,4 from counter's.

code :

```
for(i=1;i<=4;i++){
console.log(var'?');
}
```

If it would have been a array I would have used simply `var[i]` but these are individually so how do I append counters to them.

Comment: It's a bad approach, use an array.

Comment: without using `eval` you won't be able to access scoped variables, however you could make use of an object to store dynamic properties as `obj['var' + i]`.

Comment: I can't, do you have any solution..?

Comment: Seriously though, it's only four variables, might as well write it as `console.log(var1, var2, var3, var4)`. Not exactly a lot of writing.

Comment: @zzzzBov : could you post a detailed answer. :)

Comment: I need to run a for more particularly @zzzzBov

Answer (score 1):

If your variables are global, you can access them as properties of the global object (`window` for browsers):

```
for(var i=1; i<=4; i++){
    console.log( window['var' + i] );
}
```

However, if they're in function scope, that will not be an option for you.  In that case, you'll have to use `eval` which is **strongly discouraged**.  Here's how you would do it, though:

```
for(var i=1; i<=4; i++){
    eval('console.log( var' + i + ' );');
}
```

Comment: I  can't get it to run with the window (global object thing ).

Comment: That will only work if the variables are global (defined outside of any function scope).